# Different colors with Photoshop or Web browser over the same image

Tags: image, colors, photoshop, rgb, srgb

One of my clients is a painter and he has realized there's a color difference between the colors on an image looking it through the website with his web browser (Internet Explorer 8) and the same image on Photoshop.

He wants to get the exact same color looking it on Photoshop or on **any** web browser.

The image is saved normally ("save as" and NOT "save for web"). (after he noticed a little improve doing it like this)

Why is this? Is it possible to see the exact same colors on both applications?
Is it maybe because of the "color profile" on both applications? (He is currently using sRGB IEC61966-2.1 on Photoshop)

Thanks.

Comment: It may simply be IE's inability to render colors correctly, look at other browsers (Firefox,chrome etc) and they will have the correct colors. Unfortunately you cant avoid it only solution I found is using IE specific coloring for the surrounding site to balance it off. Not also that different monitors and different graphics cards may also have a slight difference in color

Comment: Yeah, i know about the different monitor problems and about the difference of colors between operative systems or devices (such as ipad or mobile phones). I was just wondering if there's any solution for this problem as my client is so obsess with his colors...
Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a concept known as "web safe colors". It is a series of colors, and the way that browsers implement them, to try to make colors as consistent across as many different monitors as possible. Unfortunately, it may be simply impossible to get your image in the web browser to look as good as it does in Photoshop. Photoshop is a tool that's been designed with the intent of making images look as great as possible, web browsers are not. Save for web will try to make the image compatible with web safe colors.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to explain it to my client... :)